# Checking day of the month and year giving me incorrect results

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to check the day of the month but it is not working. Please help me on this

```
  function daysInMonth(month, year) {
     var length =  new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
     for(var i = 1; i < = length; i++)
     {
         console.log(new Date(year,month,i).getDay());
     }
  };
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/PCjd8/1/) is the fiddle. It returns me incorrect results..

Comment: Why do you think that it's incorrect?

Comment: `.getDay()` is day of week. use `.getDate()` or just `i` (day of month) again in the loop.

Comment: I have tested it with 2012, 12. Starting and ending index dates are wrong according to the calender.. And as everyone knows that day index starts from 0.

Comment: @PaulS. Logging i returns the day count. But I just wanted to know what day that i is in that year and month

Comment: Oh, then you solved your own problem; index starts from 0 applies to months too (your demo is currently Jan 2013).

Comment: Isn't i always the day you are looking for? console.log(i) returns 1-31 in december. http://jsfiddle.net/PCjd8/5/ - Or what am i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct code:

```
function daysInMonth( month, year ) {
    var day;
    for( var i = 1 ; i <= new Date( year, month, 0 ).getDate() ; i++ ) {
        day = new Date( year, month-1, i );
        console.log( day, day.getDay() );
    }

};

daysInMonth( 12, 2012 );
```

The issue was due to the fact that months are indexed 0-11. Provided that first day of the week is Sunday:

```
daysInMonth( 12, 2012 );

Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 6 //Sat
Sun Dec 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 0 //Sun
Mon Dec 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 1 //Mon
    ...
Mon Dec 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) 1 //Mon
```

---

Alternative, shorter code:

```
function daysInMonth( month, year ) {
    for( var i = new Date( year, month, 0 ).getDate(), d = new Date( year, month-1, 1 ).getDay() ; i-- ; )
        console.log( d++ % 7 );
};
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks. May I know does it work if we pass year 0000 or 0001,0002 or 9999 ?

Comment: _Date_ should be able to take up to 100,000,000 days on either side of _January 1st 1970 UTC_ without trouble, i.e. _271702 BCE_ to _275642 CE_ . The prefixing of 0s can produce unexpected behaviour though as literals of the form `0+[0-7]+` mean you're writing in octal, not decimal.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor takes param *month* as an integer between `0` and `11`, so your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCjd8/1/), which uses `daysInMonth(12,2012);​` is actually finding the days of the week in `daysInMonth(0,2013);​`, i.e. January 2013 not December 2012.

Here is some code that will make it work letting you use months as `1` to `12`

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    var i, length =  new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); // get last day no. of previous month ( month 0 - 11 )
    month = month - 1; // set month int to what we want
    for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        console.log(new Date(year,month,i).getDay()); // continue as before
    }
};

daysInMonth(12,2012);
```

Comment: No Paul S, It gives the the exact result. Here the thing is it takes month count from 1 - 12. Try to pass Feb and 2003.  You will get the exact result. According to your comment it should return 29. But it returns 28.

Comment: @A.V `Date(year, month, 0)` => 0 less than one, subtract 1 day, => last day of previous month

Comment: @SoI With the code from your fiddle, if you tried to pass Feb as `2` and used `2003`, you'd get the number of days in the month for _February 2003_ (which is 28) and then you'd do the days of the week of 1 to 28 of _January 2003_.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
console.log(new Date('12/15/2012').getDay());​
```

Paul S. was right, works like this:

```
console.log(new Date(2012, 11, 15));​
```

Appears that months start from 0, in your example:

```
daysInMonth(11,2012);​
```

Comment: In my example month starts from 1. So 12 is valid

Comment: months are from 0 to 11, you are writing 12, so that's incorrect